# Search time when storing hashset of all cases of SHA1 in database

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, hashset, sha1

I am researching for sha1 collision.

The size of the hashset in all cases of sha1 is 2^160. Assuming you put it in the aws database, how long will it take to retrieve the record? Is there an area defined as how many seconds it takes to retrieve a record in mysql or mssql documentation? Also, what database type of aws do you think is good for a huge amount of 2^160?

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: There are 10 ^ 50 atoms in the earth which is 2 ^ 166, so I think you're going to find this difficult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve *one* row from any *suitably indexed* table will take "a few" milliseconds.

Said another way, a single program can fetch hundreds, maybe thousands, of row, one at a time, from the table *indexed by that sha1 column* in one second.

To understand how this is possible, read about how a `BTree` works.

The number of bits in the key (160) has very little impact on what I said above.  And 2^160 is simply the maximum number of *distinct* values for that key.

The only significant difference between looking it up on AWS and our personal laptop is the network latency.

If you are inserting a row but want to first check for the sha1 already being there, simply do the insert, then check for a "duplicate key" error.  Or use `INSERT IGNORE...`  Or use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...`  The Insert must (effectively) do a `SELECT` first to see if the will be a dup key -- essentially no extra effort.

Think back to how your grandparents used to look up a word in a book called a dictionary or telephone directory or atlas.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to store that much data, on aws or anywhere else.  Nor is it possible to generate that much data in any conceivable amount of time.

Comment: Knowing that this is a very large number, I don't think it will come out in a reasonable amount of time. I just want to calculate an imaginary estimated time by finding how much time it takes to retrieve a record from a db document under the "assuming" that it is put in dababase. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to calculate an imaginary estimated time

About 4 seconds.

Imagine B-Tree on a 160 bit key.  If each Page is 8000 bytes, and the page pointer is also 160 bits that's 25 key values per page. 2^160 ~ 25^35, so there would be 35 levels in the B-Tree, so 35 IO's to get to the leaf level.

This would necessarily be a planet-sized distributed system, so allow 100ms per IO, and that's something under 4 seconds.